# React + Redux, where should my UI-related calculations go, container components, or reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a mid to large react/redux project, and I'm trying to find out the best practice for react/redux.

For example, if I have a **pie chart** component, which will take a simple array as prop:

```
[{
  label: 'a',
  value: 10
}, {
  label: 'b',
  value: 6
}, ...]
```

but the source data I fetch from the API server may be something like this:

```
{
  a: {
    value1: 15,
    value2: 3,
    value3: 7,
    ...
  },
  b: { ... }
}
```

now I have to do some calculations to get the result data (like value1 -value2 + value3... maybe some filters...), the question is, should I put this calculation in a **reducer** (I feel it's more like a *getter*, which will be passed as a prop to a component via `connect`, like `getCartProducts` [in this example](https://git.io/v1PRR)), or a **container component** (may be a *Dashboard* in this case)?

I think both options make sense:

- in a reducer: we can keep our component clean, and put all the logics in a same place.
- in a container: because it's UI-related, and if the computed data is not reusable (only for that pie chart), we can keep this kind of calculations in related components.

If I choose reducers, then another question comes. Should I save the computed data in the store? Or just save the source data, and calculate it everytime I render the component? [The old React doc](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.14-stable/docs/docs/03-interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.md#what-shouldnt-go-in-state) said that you should not save computed data in state, not sure if is true for redux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Usually:**

1. store should includes minimal possible state.
2. derrived data is calculated in mapStateToProps through [**reselect**](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect),
   to memoize the result. Calculation will be invoked at once;

**But:**
if derived data's shape differs from shape that is used in an application (or you need some calculations), then 
you may calculate right after fetch. (for example it may be normalizing data)

I think you should persist collection rather then array, since to get data by key much simpler.
and if you are not going to edit values of particular items, you can precalculate them in a reducer.

**For example calculating through selectors:**

was used selectors composition, to avoid recalculations while updating filter:

```
import map from 'lodash/map';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getFilterKeys=(state)=>state.filter; //['a','b','c']
//(btw it's just example... filter may be in props);

const getItems=(state)=>state.entities.items;


const calculateValues = (item) => item.value1 - item.value2 + item.value3;

export const getItemsForChart = createSelector(
  [getItems],
  (items)=> map(items,(item,key)=>({label:key, value:calculateValues(item)}))
);

export const getItemsForChartWithFilter = createSelector(
  [getItemsForChart, getFilterKeys],
  (items, filterKeys)=> items.filter(item=>filterKeys.some(key=>key==item.label))
);
```

.

```
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  return {
    chartData:getItemsForChartWithFilter(state)
  };
};
```

btw order in collection is not guaranteed, therefore maybe you should receive from server array of keys in addition to collection. Then code will be a bit different...